# Flask and PyJWT retrieve authorization header

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jwt

There is a REST client that makes HTTP requests to the server. REST client sends a request which contains a header

```
Authorization=Bearer someValidBase64
```

Now I have a server application in Python 3.8, Flask 1.1.1, PyJWT==1.7.1.

```
@app.route(my_rest_end_point)
def get_service_payments():
    authorization_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')

    # It prints correctly: Bearer someValidBase64
    print("Authorization header:\n" + authorization_header)

    # Details from that header
    user_permissions = jwt.decode(authorization_header)
```

It fails with

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 188, in _load
    raise DecodeError('Invalid header padding')
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Invalid header padding
```

### What I tried

```
authorization_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
print("Authorization header:\n" + authorization_header)
cleared_header =  authorization_header[7:]
print("cleared_header:\n" + cleared_header)
user_permissions = jwt.decode(cleared_header)
```

It will print

```
Authorization header:
Bearer someValidBase64
cleared_header:
someValidBase64
```

It fails again because the token itself has structure
someValidBase64.otherValidPart
so there is a dot **`.`**.

Comment: `Bearer` is not part of the token, you should split the string and take only the token itself to the `jwt.decode` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is `authorization_header` consists of the value `"Bearer someValidBase64"`. Now when you try to decode this, you are facing this error because the prefix "Bearer" is attached to it.

Make sure you store only the base64 part of the string inside `authorization_header` without the prefix so that you can decode it successfully.

**Update:**

As I understand, the `authorization_header` consists of a JWT token and since you're trying to decode a JWT token, make sure your `authorization_header` is in the format of `xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz`
If you find it in any other format than this, make sure you strip the string so that only this format of the JWT token is extracted.

Comment: I will try in a week